# How to add middleware to specific route on Slim Framework

Tags: php, api, slim

I'm building an API using Slim Framework and I wrote a script that creates the routes and add It's middlewares dinamically. The problem is that for some reason the routes are being applied to every route in the app. How can I apply the middleware on one route only?

**This is the route.cfg file**

```
#[HTTP Verb] [Route] [Controller::method] [middleware|middleware]

GET /usuario/autenticar UsuarioController:autenticar log
GET /usuario/listar[/{id}] UsuarioController:listar log|autenticar
GET /usuario/encerrarSessao UsuarioController:encerrarSessao log|autenticar
POST /usuario/cadastrar UsuarioController:cadastrar log|autenticar
PUT /usuario/editar UsuarioController:editar log|autenticar
DELETE /usuario/deletar UsuarioController:deletar log|autenticar
```

**This is the script that read the routes file**

```
<?php

use Slim\App;
use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;

return function (App $app) {
    $container = $app->getContainer();

$routesFile = file(__DIR__ . '/routes.cfg');

foreach ($routesFile as $fileLine) {
    $fileLine = str_replace("\n", "", $fileLine);
    $fileLine = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $fileLine);

    $args = explode(' ', $fileLine);

    if (strpos($fileLine, '#') !== false || count($args) < 3) continue;

    $verb = array_key_exists(0, $args) ? $args[0] : null;
    $endpoint = array_key_exists(1, $args) ? $args[1] : null;
    $controller = array_key_exists(2, $args) ? $args[2] : null;
    $routeMiddleware = array_key_exists(3, $args) ? $args[3] : null;

    $app->{$verb}($endpoint, "$controller");

    if (isset($routeMiddleware) && strlen($routeMiddleware) > 0) {
        $routeMiddleware = trim($routeMiddleware);

        $middlewares = explode('|', $routeMiddleware);

        foreach ($middlewares as $middlewareFunction) {
            $app->add(function($request, $response, $next) use ($middlewareFunction) {
                return Middleware::{$middlewareFunction}($request, $response, $next);
            });
        }
    }
}

};
```

**And this is my Middleware class**

```
    <?php

use Slim\App;

class Middleware {
    public static function autenticar($request, $response, $next) {
        //Do stuff...
        return $next($request, $response);
    }

    public static function log($request, $response, $next) {
        //Do stuff...
        return $next($request, $response);
    }
}
```

Comment: By "the routes are being applied to every route in the app", do you mean "the middleware is being applied to every route in the app" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the problem is that this line registers the middleware for all routes:

```php
$app->add(function($request, $response, $next) use ($middlewareFunction) {
```

Registering a middleware for a single route works like this:

```php
$this->get('/', \App\Action\HomeIndexAction::class)
    ->add(MyMiddleware::class);
```

I would try to change your code like this:

```php
<?php

use Slim\App;
use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;

return function (App $app) {
    $routesFile = file(__DIR__ . '/routes.cfg');

    foreach ($routesFile as $fileLine) {
        $fileLine = str_replace("\n", '', $fileLine);
        $fileLine = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $fileLine);

        $args = explode(' ', $fileLine);

        if (strpos($fileLine, '#') !== false || count($args) < 3) {
            continue;
        }

        $verb = $args[0] ?? null;
        $endpoint = $args[1] ?? null;
        $controller = $args[2] ?? null;
        $routeMiddleware = $args[3] ?? null;

        // This line has changed
        $route = $app->{$verb}($endpoint, $controller);

        if (isset($routeMiddleware) && $routeMiddleware !== '') {
            $routeMiddleware = trim($routeMiddleware);

            $middlewares = explode('|', $routeMiddleware);

            foreach ($middlewares as $middlewareFunction) {
                // This line has changed
                $route->add(function ($request, $response, $next) use ($middlewareFunction) {
                    return Middleware::{$middlewareFunction}($request, $response, $next);
                });
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Well, that's the thing, I'm trying to write the routes based on the .cfg file definitions and  execute a controller's method. That works fine but when I try to add the middlewares It is applied to al routes.

Comment: Oh! You're right! As obvious as It was I didn't realize I could store the route on a variable and then add the middleware. Thank you.